# Access Database Query same vaue for all rows problem/issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

so in Access Database I have 2 tables, say Table 1 and Table 2. Both tables have a price column (price 1.Table1 and price2.table2) and other columns as well in both tables. Information in other columns are the same, only difference between tables are prices.

I have created a query where it pulls all the data from Table 1 and next to that it pulls price2.table2 column and calculates the difference between prices in another column.

The problem I am having is when it copies and pastes price2.table2 , it copies the same number for all rows and I cant figure it out why. I basically need it to copy price2 column but it does not.

Would appreciate your help.

SQL is as follows

```
Select table1.price1, table2.price2, 
        [table1].[price1] - [table2].[price2] AS price_difference 
FROM table1, table2
```

Comment: First use a JOIN it is far more reliable and predictable

Comment: It is always useful when asking an sql question to show us the schema for the relevant tables

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, I am not very much familiar with SQL or MS Access. if you could clarify what you mean by schema for tables, I will do my best to provide more info.

Comment: The table definition, column anmes and datatypes etc

Comment: The "why" is lack of JOIN clause. This invokes a Cartesian relationship - every record of each table associates with every record of other table. How are these tables related?